# Find marginal density at a point

Tags: self-learning, density-function

Given the following joint density function:

\begin{equation}
f (x,y) =
\begin{cases}
 2& \text{} 0 \le x \le 1-y, 0 \le y \le 1\\
0  &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Find $f_{y}(1/2)$.

Since this is a continuous distribution, is the answer $0$. Or do I have to integrate the marginal density of $y$ from $0$ to $1/2$ or from $1/2$ to $1$.

Comment: You have to find the marginal density $f_Y(y)=\int f(x,y)\,dx$ first and then set $y=1/2$.

Comment: $f_y(1/2)$ isn't the probability of getting $1/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first calculate the marginal density or you calculate directly:

\begin{eqnarray*} f_Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
& = & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right)\; dx \\
& = & \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{2}}2\; dx \\
& = & 2\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}